# using ajax to load json from an online site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm loading json from another site with jquery's `$.ajax()` function. The request is completing successfully, but how can I, now, access the json and save it to a javascript array?

Here is my code so far:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    data:{},
    url:'http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/',
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR);
    },
    success:function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: What is the response from the server?  What is in `msg` in the success handler?  If `msg` has what you're looking for then use it.

Comment: `msg` would already be that variable. Its value can be copied to another variable from another scope. But, anything accessing that other variable will have to wait for the Ajax request to finish, which is precisely what `success` is for.

Comment: @SLaks What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate through returned `JSON`. try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    data:{},
    url:'http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/',
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR);
    },
    success:function(msg){
        if (msg) {
          var myArray = [];
          $.each(msg, function(i, item) {
             //do whatever you want for each row in json
             myArray.push(item);
          });
        }
    }
});
```

Also look into [$.parseJSON(msg);](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) that might work for your as well.

Comment: JSONP does not need to be parsed

Comment: Getting unexpected token coming from the call. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: @cr0ss How do I fix that as it is not in my control?

Comment: @MrGuru The response is JSON, not JSONP (no "padding"). You need to determine if the API actually supports JSONP and, if so, what it expects the callback parameter to be called as it isn't using jQuery's default of `callback`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski now i am getting the same error as when I was using getJSON. The cross domain origin. Is there any way I can get the json data and turn the value at "1" into an array?

Comment: @MrGuru If the service doesn't support either JSONP responses or CORS allowances, you'll probably have to write a server-side proxy script on your own origin to fetch the JSON for the client.